# is there a way to break from this inherited padding in css?

Tags: css

I have this HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>content <span>more</span></li>
</ul>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
li{
  padding: 30px;
}

span{
  padding-top: -20px;
}
```

the padding on the `span` does not take effect. I could work around it by changing the HTML, but now that I was faced with this, I wanted to learn whether there is a work around or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`padding-top` on inline element wouldn't work! Use block element, or set `span { display:block }`.

Answer (score 1):

Set your `<span>` to `{display:inline-block}`